# Count number of queries in each page load of Laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to achive this by listening for query events but I don't seem to have any idea of how I got the count. This is only retrieving list of queries as the callback function cannot modified to return a count variable:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    var_dump('<pre>'.$query->sql.</pre>);
});
```

I need a solution to count each page executed queries by Laravel.

Comment: You can use `$queries = DB::getQueryLog();` but you should enable the log first : `DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();`

Comment: should I do that when I want to use this also in production !

Comment: nop it recommended to use for debuging only ! you can use `if (App::environment('local')) {
    DB::enableQueryLog();
}`

Comment: but I need this for specific users in a production site

Comment: Laravel can optionally log in memory all queries that have been run for the current request. Be aware that in some cases, such as when inserting a large number of rows, this can cause the application to use excess memory. -> [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

Comment: that's why I only need a way to count query and send them back into a view. Is it possible with DB::listen() or somwhere else rather than enableQueryLog ?

Comment: Is it for all models? Or just a few?

Comment: A good feature request may be. Total number of seconds taken by all queries can help.

Comment: Make life easier for yourself and add debug bar. Its perfect for this type of thing to see whats going on in your application. [https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: This required APP_DEBUG=true. On production site I cannot just make app_debug to true. Why I need to do that on a production site? it is a different story.

Answer (score 17):

Super old question but when I searched for a way to do this here is where I ended up. Doesn't seem to be a built-in way to get the count but simply doing something like this will get you what you need;

```
$count = 0;
DB::listen(function ($query) use (&$count) {
    $count++;
});
```

You might want to store the count somewhere more suitable but this will give you and any others coming here from Google the general idea.

Comment: Worked for me!!